# MVC configure route for mobile controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, .net-4.0

In my MVC 4 web appication if I access the Home page I call the following url:

*sitename/Home*

I now added a subfolder called Mobile to the Controllers folder.How can I configure routing to be able to call the Home controller in the Mobile folder like this

*sitename/Mobile/Home*

**Here's my RegisterRoutes method:**

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
        namespaces: new string[] { "Test.Controllers" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Mobile",
        url: "Mobile/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
        namespaces: new string[] { "Test.Controllers.Mobile" }
    );


}
```

Comment: Try swapping the MapRoute calls.

Comment: @dav_i You should put this as an answer.

Comment: @DavidG I have a busted finger at the moment so my WPM are down a little - answer posted!

Comment: @dav_i There's no excuse for slow typing soldier! Buckle up! :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC routes are order dependant and should go in order of most specific to most generic.

At the moment, if you type the url `Mobile/Home/Index` the routing will try and map that to:

- controller: Mobile
- action: Home
- id: Index

using the default route and never get to your intended route map.

If you swap the `MapRoute` declarations around, then MVC will see that it starts with "Mobile" and use that route as intended.

Comment: As a side note, it may be better to use Areas for this kind of functionality.

Answer (score -1):

@dav_i is 100% correct in that the route needs to be before the other one.  The URL for mobile has Mobile in the URL, so you would have to have Mobile in any action links or redirects...  So ideally, in your global.asax, you'd try to detect whether the browser is mobile, and redirect within there...  But you still have to manage having Mobile in the URL.  That's because functions like Url.Action and Html.ActionLink expect the controller and action to be the full URL, and this:

```
@Url.Action("Action", "Control")
```

produces:

```
/Control/Action
```

And as such, you'd have to handle this.  Alternatively, you could use mobile views without having to worry about this.  See [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/aspnet-mvc-4-mobile-features).

Comment: The question is about routing, not detecting client type.

Comment: And I answered that with `The URL for mobile has Mobile in the URL, so you would have to have Mobile in any action links or redirects`, but there are other logistical concerns I was also trying to address.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question, the answer is what @dav_i wrote in his comment.

Comment: @dav_i is 100% correct, I wasn't addressing that, but part of `How can I configure routing to be able to call the Home controller in the Mobile folder like this`, you have to call that controller by making the appropriate request, so I disagree.

Comment: It's OK to disagree, but to "configure routing" in MVC means to set up your routes, not determine if a browser is mobile or not. OP makes no mention whether he has already solved that part or not, nor whether he already has the correct `Url.Action` statements.

Comment: Also note that he wants to route to completely different controllers that exist in their own namespace.